# Trying to understand a proof about oscillation in a point

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have had troubles in understanding a proof concerning the oscillation in a point. The definitions and properties of the oscillation are here:[image: Definition of scilation in a point]

[image: Properties of the oscilation]

[image: Proof which I dont understand]

The problem is in Theorem 18, the part when is stated that the oscillation of $f$ in $I_x \cap [a,b]$ is less than $\epsilon$. As far as I understand, for corolary 1 of Theorem 17, there exists an open interval with center $x$, such that the oscilation of each point is less than $\epsilon$. But I don't see how it implies that the oscillation in the INTERVAL(i.e., $sup f(I)-inf f(I)$, where I is the interval) is less than $\epsilon$. This because the oscillation in each point is the infimum of all the oscillations around that point, and maybe there are larger oscillations than the infimum around that point...

Comment: In spite of my weak Portugese (...well actually nonexistant) it seems to me you are trying to *use* Corollary 1 of Theorem 17 to justify this statement.  But actually it is more elementary:  take any one point $x$ at which you know that $\omega(f;x)<\epsilon$.  Then you know that there has to be at least one aberto interval $I_x$ that contains $x$ and the oscillation of $f$ on $I_x$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.  That is just by definition.  Then the argument goes that there is an entire collection of intervals $\{I_x: x\in [a,b]\}$ forming a cover of $[a,b]$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand the concept of oscillation of a function. Hopefully it will be of some use to you.

The oscillation of function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ at point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is defined as $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \left(\sup_{(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}f\,-\inf_{(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}f\right)\ .$$

Since $$\sup_{(x-1,x+1)}f \leq \sup_{(x-2,x+2)}f\quad \text{ and } \quad \inf_{(x-1,x+1)}f \geq \inf_{(x-2,x+2)}f$$ this indicates that function $\varepsilon \mapsto \sup_{(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}f$ is increasing and function  $\varepsilon \mapsto \sup_{(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}f$ is decreasing. This makes function $$\varepsilon \mapsto \sup_{(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}f\,-\inf_{(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)}f$$ increasing; in other words, the oscillation over a long interval is larger than the oscillation over a short interval.

- If you know that the oscillation over an interval (around point $x$) is less than $1$ (for example) then you know that the oscillation at point $x$ is less than $1$ as well.
- If you know that oscillation at point $x$ is larger than $2$ (for example) then you know that the oscillation over any interval containing $x$ is larger than $2$ as well.

Comment: I agree in everything. Nevertheless the problem is that if I know that the oscillation on every point x in an interval is less than $\epsilon$, then it does not imply the oscillation in the interval to be less than $\epsilon$ too. Take any continuous function, large as you wish.